# UI is not updating with NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I am downloading hundreds of files with `NSURLSessionConfiguration`. I am updating a progress label for each downloaded file, from method

```
 -(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location.
```

Suddenly it stopped updating progress label. I have tried `performSelectorOnMainThread`,`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` but to no avail.

What could be wrong? How can I update UI from *didFinishDownloadingToURL* method?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does it run on main thread?

The most reliable solution for `UIView is`

```
[View performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(Update:) withObject: ProgressObj waitUntilDone:FALSE];
```

It will guarantee that the UI update is being executed on correct thread. If you are using Core Graphics - keep Context pointer as your class variable. However, I prefer `CALayer` object for such kind manipulations